# Запросы в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как реализовать запросы на laravel?

```
$posts = Poste::Where('category_id', $category_id)
  ->get();
```

При этом мне нежно сделать проверку, например на поле `price`, то есть:

```
$posts = Poste::Where('category_id', $category_id)
  ->Where('price', $price)
  ->get();
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `price` может и не быть, то есть быть пустым, если `price` приходит пустым, то он начинает искать все посты, у которых поле `price` пустое. Как сделать если `$price` приходит пусто, то при запросе, `price` не учитывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*На моей памяти нет метода `Where` (с большой буквы) - только `where`.*
Теперь к вопросу. Для использования динамический запросов сохрани `Builder` в переменную

```
// Довольно странное имя модели Poste
$builder = Poste::where('category_id', $category_id);
if($price){
    $builder->where('price', $price);
}
$posts = $builder->get();
```

Почитай [хорошие практики Laravel об именовании](https://laravel.ru/posts/889)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать метод билдера [when](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_when):

```
$posts = Poste::where('category_id', $category_id)
    ->when(!empty($price), function($query) use($price) {
      return $query->where('price', $price)
    })
    ->get();
```